# How to highlight search results with 2 or more html-elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I used mark.js for resolving subject, however, it's not working for cases like

```
<p><b>3</b> results found</p>
```

So if I try to search "3 results found" I will have 0 matches. However, browser can handle cases like that with ctrl+F. How can I do it using javascript?

Answer (score -1):

To search across multiple HTML elements you'll have to enable the option `separateWordSearch` of mark.js – which is enabled by default. Since you haven't posted a code example I assume that you've explicite deactivated it.

Here is an example:

```js
new Mark(document.querySelector("p")).mark("3 results found");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/mark.min.js"></script>
<p><b>3</b> results found</p>
```

If you need an option to search in multiple HTML elements without this option, you'll have to submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/new).

Comment: Well, there are 2 problems I faced with it: 1)"Android N" search query will highlight "android" and all "n"(unacceptable); 2) It will highlight them as 2 separately.

Comment: >If you need an option to search in multiple HTML elements without this option, you'll have to submit a feature request here.

Unfortunately, I don't have a time for future release that's why I'm asking any way to implement it.

Comment: You're right, but you'll have to choose the least bad variant. You can either enable `separateWordSearch` and fix your thread question or disable it and search "android n" only in combination. Or, as mentioned, you could submit a feature request to the plugins repository to receive an option that solves both use cases.

Comment: `I don't have a time for future release that's why I'm asking any way to`   
In this case, please tell us more about your use case. Can't you just put "3" outside of `<b>`? Btw: You could post a bounty [here](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/mark.js/issues?tracker_ids=11315069) to speed up this feature when submitted.

Comment: Ok, so the whole story is that we are using chromium-base web-browser in our app to show htmlBody of emails. But there is a feature: if user used a search in our app and opened an email from search result, web-browser should highlight found results in htmlBody. As I mentioned, using mark.js worked fine until we test it with some complicated cases like I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I'll have to say sorry – mark.js is already the best keyword highlighter and there is no other component that can handle this, so you'll definitely have to submit a feature request. Maybe it'll be implemented this week. How urgent do you need this functionality?

Comment: As an alternative idea: You could enable `separateWordSearch` and implement a custom function `filter` to ignore highlights of single characters like `n` in your case (described in [the documentation](https://markjs.io/#filter)).

Comment: Well, thanks for a try though :) I'll submit a request, but I have a weak in a best case.

I was thinking about something like but I don't think that this will do fine.